# Adding Facebook SDK to android studio project using Gradle. Manifest merger failed error coming. Multiple support libraries conflict. What to do?

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk

My app.gradle file contains :-

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Gradle console error output**

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38
  >   is also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 value=(25.3.1).
  >   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.

Comment: post your gradle.

Comment: Put this inside your Android Manifest - `tools:replace="android:value"`

Comment: Posted my app gradle.build file dependencies i am using.

Comment: change version of `support:design` & `support:appcompat` to `25.3.1` instead of `26.+`. also use facebook dependancy like `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'`

Comment: Thank You build successfully after version change. I am using compileSdkVersion 26. Should i also change it to 25 as studio is showing red lines saying compileSdkVersion and support library version should be same. This means that i am not using the latest support libraries and android version. Will there be any feature i will not be able to use as they always suggest to use latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use latest Facebook SDK.

You should use this.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'
```

Then **clean** and **rebuild** the project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ya latest facebook SDK uses support library 25.3.1 which is causing conflicts as i was using 26.0.0-alpha1.